# NSPredicate limit results

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to limit array of objects getting with `[NSArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate]` for better performance.

My Code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.Name contains[c] %@", searchText]; 
NSArray *filteredArray = [self.dataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

My `dataArray` contains about 30.000 objects and I want to limit result array 50. (I need some break statement after 50 match found.) How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `NSPredicate` in conjunction with an [`NSFetchRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use simple `for-in` loop, `NSMutableArray` builder and `-[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:]` method.

```
NSMutableArray *builder = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];
for (id object in array) {
    if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:object]) {
        [builder addObject:object];
        if (builder.count >= 50) break;
    }
}
```

---

I noticed you tagged the question by `Core Data`. If you can use `NSFetchRequest`, then just set its `fetchLimit` to 50.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer :). Do you think I should go with NSFetchRequest? Which one makes performance better?

Comment: If you already have your array of objects it is better to filter this array and not to query the database. Though if you have NSFetchRequest to get array of objects its better to set predicate to it and set fetch limit.

Comment: With Core Data you can obtain objects in **two ways**: first is **fetch request** (here is obvious to **set the fetch limit**), the second is **traversing object graph** by calling relationship getter (like `user.followers`, or so) here is better to just **filter it in loop**. So it depends on what you already have, but if the array is that huge, you may try both variants and see the performance difference. Doing fetch request may need more complicated predicate.

Comment: @Tricertops Do you know how to use fetchLimit with "at"FetchRequest syntax?

Comment: @3h4x No idea. I didn’t touch Core Data in years.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
myArray = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:myPredicate];

if ([myArray count] > resultLimit) {
        myArray = [myArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, resultLimit)];
}
```

Comment: Helped me a lot, because my result was already filtrated, but had to be limited too in another method. This solution is more performant than iterating again through it :)